# Ubuntu 21.04 Power mode

Tags: performance, 21.04

So, I use AIO device and that means this device always plugged in, and I can use performance mode but every time I reboot it auto-set to balance mode. How can I use performance mode permanently?

[image: This what I talk about]

Comment: Do you mind running a startup command that sets the mode to Performance once user logs in? But it should be from system startup itself.

Comment: @UnKNOWn I just dunno what the command I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon is providing all the details required for command line.

Installation Steps

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon.git
cd power-profiles-daemon
meson _build -Dprefix=/usr
ninja -v -C _build install
```

to know which profile is active run below command

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.PowerProfiles --object-path /net/hadess/PowerProfiles
```

some of the result

```
  interface net.hadess.PowerProfiles {
    methods:
    signals:
    properties:
      readwrite s ActiveProfile = 'balanced';
```

to set the Performance mode run the below command

```
gdbus call --system --dest net.hadess.PowerProfiles --object-path /net/hadess/PowerProfiles --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set 'net.hadess.PowerProfiles' 'ActiveProfile' "<'performance'>"
```

Available Profiles

1. power-saver
2. balanced
3. performance

Try this command and reboot and see for the persistence. If the profile is changing back to what you dont want, then put the above command in startup command list.

Comment: Also, there is another way:

I copied your command to set performance mode and wrote easy python code, then I just set it to autoloading by systemD. Works just fine!

https://www.fosslinux.com/42796/how-to-auto-execute-linux-startup-scripts-and-commands.htm

Comment: would be nice to have that python script published.

Comment: the instruction to compile it need stuff installed: cmake, gudev and who knows what else...

Answer (score 9):

Actually there is an easy way which does not require any compilation or script writing.
Simply put the command `powerprofilesctl set performance` into your Startup Applications or into a file that will be run during startup.

Comment: Thanks, it actually way easier than to use a python script

Comment: My prefered answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm on 21.10. Thanks!

Comment: how to show the current power profile?

Comment: `powerprofilesctl get` in the terminal or go to `Settings/ Power/ Power Mode`