# How to change default laptop power mode 21.04

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, performance, 21.04

Ubuntu 21.04 comes with new native [power modes](https://fostips.com/changing-power-mode-easy-ubuntu-21-04/) which can be changed in settings. These settings are powered by the [GNOME power-profiles-daemon](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-power-profiles-daemon). However, I've noticed that power mode on my Dell XPS 13 (model 9310 with kernel 5.11.0-31-generic) is always set to balanced by default, whether the laptop is plugged in or on battery.

I would like to set the power mode default to high performance, either all the time or at least when my laptop is plugged in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: thanks to [UnKNOWn](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/unknown) for their comment, seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 21.04 Power mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340608/ubuntu-21-04-power-mode)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion!